# Counting the occurence based on overlapping intervals (HH:MM) in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with the exact time and quantity of e-vehicles charging at a charging station and its charging power in kW.

What I am trying to do is to calculate how many e-vehicles are charging at the exact same time (taking into account `start` and `end` times), and according to that, calculate the required charging power (sum up the `power_kW`) needed for each hour. For example, from `18-19h` I need only 100kW of power.

Below I shared a part of the data, I obviously have the data for all the 24 hours, and for each hour I should have a total needed charging station power in kW.
Obviously, if one vehicle finishes charging at 20:50, and another one starts at 20:50 - they overlap and I need to count `2*power_kW`. Also, in some slots, I have more than 1 vehicle starting and finishing at the same time.

I find it hard to do it fast and automatically with the code, given that the times are in `hour:minute` format, so I seek help here. I checked similar posts and couldn't find anything to bring me to a solution on my own.

**Does someone have an idea how to do this efficently and correctly?**

Input data:

```py
import pandas as pd
mycolumns = ['start_timeslot', 'start', 'end', 'power_kW', 'vehicle_count']
data = [['18H-19H', '18:26', '20:27', 100, 1], ['19H-20H', '19:06', '21:16', 100, 1], 
        ['19H-20H', '19:19', '21:16', 100, 1], ['19H-20H', '19:36', '21:33', 100, 1], 
        ['19H-20H', '19:54', '20:19', 100, 2], ['19H-20H', '19:55', '22:01', 100, 1],
        ['20H-21H', '20:04', '22:06', 100, 1], ['20H-21H', '20:11', '22:04', 100, 2], 
        ['20H-21H', '20:15', '22:04', 100, 1], ['20H-21H', '20:16', '22:04', 100, 1], 
        ['20H-21H', '20:17', '22:08', 100, 1], ['20H-21H', '20:19', '22:09', 100, 1],
        ['20H-21H', '20:20', '22:01', 100, 2], ['20H-21H', '20:22', '22:35', 100, 1], 
        ['20H-21H', '20:28', '22:34', 100, 2], ['20H-21H', '20:29', '22:22', 100, 1], 
        ['20H-21H', '20:30', '22:14', 100, 1], ['20H-21H', '20:31', '22:10', 100, 1],
        ['20H-21H', '20:37', '22:31', 100, 1], ['20H-21H', '20:41', '22:29', 100, 2], 
        ['20H-21H', '20:43', '22:34', 100, 1], ['20H-21H', '20:46', '22:39', 100, 1], 
        ['20H-21H', '20:47', '22:35', 100, 1], ['20H-21H', '20:52', '22:34', 100, 1],
        ['20H-21H', '20:52', '23:09', 100, 1], ['20H-21H', '20:53', '21:59', 100, 1], 
        ['20H-21H', '20:54', '21:49', 100, 1], ['20H-21H', '20:56', '22:10', 100, 1], 
        ['20H-21H', '20:56', '22:55', 100, 1], ['21H-22H', '21:03', '22:51', 100, 1],
        ['21H-22H', '21:05', '23:12', 100, 1], ['21H-22H', '21:08', '22:59', 100, 1], 
        ['21H-22H', '21:10', '23:27', 100, 1], ['21H-22H', '21:10', '23:30', 100, 1], 
        ['21H-22H', '21:15', '23:23', 100, 1], ['21H-22H', '21:19', '21:56', 100, 1],
        ['21H-22H', '21:21', '22:48', 100, 1], ['21H-22H', '21:25', '23:26', 100, 1], 
        ['21H-22H', '21:25', '23:32', 100, 1], ['21H-22H', '21:27', '22:55', 100, 1], 
        ['21H-22H', '21:27', '23:32', 100, 1], ['21H-22H', '21:33', '23:11', 100, 1],
        ['21H-22H', '21:37', '23:04', 100, 1], ['21H-22H', '21:39', '00:05', 100, 1], 
        ['21H-22H', '21:40', '23:08', 100, 1], ['21H-22H', '21:45', '23:04', 100, 1], 
        ['21H-22H', '21:49', '00:06', 100, 1], ['21H-22H', '21:54', '00:07', 100, 1],
        ['21H-22H', '21:58', '00:02', 100, 1], ['21H-22H', '21:58', '00:24', 100, 1], 
        ['22H-23H', '22:10', '00:19', 100, 1]]
        
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=mycolumns)

df
   start_timeslot   start   end     power_kW   vehicle_count
0   18H-19H        18:26    20:27   100         1
1   19H-20H        19:06    21:16   100         1
2   19H-20H        19:19    21:16   100         1
3   19H-20H        19:36    21:33   100         1
4   19H-20H        19:54    20:19   100         2
5   19H-20H        19:55    22:01   100         1
6   20H-21H        20:04    22:06   100         1
7   20H-21H        20:11    22:04   100         2
8   20H-21H        20:15    22:04   100         1
9   20H-21H        20:16    22:04   100         1
10  20H-21H        20:17    22:08   100         1
11  20H-21H        20:19    22:09   100         1
12  20H-21H        20:20    22:01   100         2
13  20H-21H        20:22    22:35   100         1
14  20H-21H        20:28    22:34   100         2
15  20H-21H        20:29    22:22   100         1
16  20H-21H        20:30    22:14   100         1
17  20H-21H        20:31    22:10   100         1
18  20H-21H        20:37    22:31   100         1
19  20H-21H        20:41    22:29   100         2
20  20H-21H        20:43    22:34   100         1
21  20H-21H        20:46    22:39   100         1
22  20H-21H        20:47    22:35   100         1
23  20H-21H        20:52    22:34   100         1
24  20H-21H        20:52    23:09   100         1
25  20H-21H        20:53    21:59   100         1
26  20H-21H        20:54    21:49   100         1
27  20H-21H        20:56    22:10   100         1
28  20H-21H        20:56    22:55   100         1
29  21H-22H        21:03    22:51   100         1
30  21H-22H        21:05    23:12   100         1
31  21H-22H        21:08    22:59   100         1
32  21H-22H        21:10    23:27   100         1
33  21H-22H        21:10    23:30   100         1
34  21H-22H        21:15    23:23   100         1
35  21H-22H        21:19    21:56   100         1
36  21H-22H        21:21    22:48   100         1
37  21H-22H        21:25    23:26   100         1
38  21H-22H        21:25    23:32   100         1
39  21H-22H        21:27    22:55   100         1
40  21H-22H        21:27    23:32   100         1
41  21H-22H        21:33    23:11   100         1
42  21H-22H        21:37    23:04   100         1
43  21H-22H        21:39    00:05   100         1
44  21H-22H        21:40    23:08   100         1
45  21H-22H        21:45    23:04   100         1
46  21H-22H        21:49    00:06   100         1
47  21H-22H        21:54    00:07   100         1
48  21H-22H        21:58    00:02   100         1
49  21H-22H        21:58    00:24   100         1
50  22H-23H        22:10    00:19   100         1
```

Expected output should be:

```
   start_timeslot   needed_power_kW   
0   18H-19H         100        
1   19H-20H         700        
2   20H-21H         3100        
3   21H-22H         4600        
4   22H-23H         4600
5   23H-00H         1800
6   00H-01H         600
```

---

I am adding an example from the real dataset, because with the proposed solutions I cannot get the correct answer for all options.

```
mycolumns = ['start_timeslot', 'start', 'end', 'power_kW', 'vehicle_count']
data = [['00H-01H', '00:05', '00:09', 200.0, 1],
       ['00H-01H', '00:35', '00:39', 200.0, 1],
       ['01H-02H', '01:05', '01:09', 200.0, 1],
       ['05H-06H', '05:34', '05:41', 200.0, 1],
       ['05H-06H', '05:54', '06:01', 200.0, 1],
       ['06H-07H', '06:20', '06:27', 200.0, 1],
       ['06H-07H', '06:44', '06:47', 200.0, 1],
       ['06H-07H', '06:59', '07:06', 200.0, 1],
       ['07H-08H', '07:18', '07:22', 200.0, 1],
       ['07H-08H', '07:36', '07:40', 200.0, 1],
       ['07H-08H', '07:49', '07:56', 200.0, 1],
       ['08H-09H', '08:01', '08:05', 200.0, 1],
       ['08H-09H', '08:08', '08:14', 200.0, 1],
       ['08H-09H', '08:14', '08:20', 200.0, 1],
       ['08H-09H', '08:21', '08:26', 200.0, 1],
       ['08H-09H', '08:28', '08:35', 200.0, 1],
       ['08H-09H', '08:35', '08:42', 200.0, 1],
       ['08H-09H', '08:42', '08:46', 200.0, 1],
       ['08H-09H', '08:49', '08:56', 200.0, 1],
       ['08H-09H', '08:55', '09:02', 200.0, 1],
       ['08H-09H', '09:00', '09:04', 200.0, 1],
       ['09H-10H', '09:07', '09:13', 200.0, 1],
       ['09H-10H', '09:13', '09:20', 200.0, 1],
       ['09H-10H', '09:25', '09:29', 200.0, 1],
       ['09H-10H', '09:31', '09:36', 200.0, 1],
       ['09H-10H', '09:37', '09:42', 200.0, 1],
       ['09H-10H', '09:43', '09:47', 200.0, 1],
       ['09H-10H', '09:49', '09:56', 200.0, 1],
       ['09H-10H', '09:55', '10:02', 200.0, 1],
       ['10H-11H', '10:01', '10:05', 200.0, 1],
       ['10H-11H', '10:06', '10:13', 200.0, 1],
       ['10H-11H', '10:12', '10:16', 200.0, 1],
       ['10H-11H', '10:18', '10:23', 200.0, 1],
       ['10H-11H', '10:23', '10:27', 200.0, 1],
       ['10H-11H', '10:29', '10:33', 200.0, 1],
       ['10H-11H', '10:35', '10:39', 200.0, 1],
       ['10H-11H', '10:41', '10:45', 200.0, 1],
       ['10H-11H', '10:47', '10:52', 200.0, 1],
       ['10H-11H', '10:53', '10:57', 200.0, 1],
       ['10H-11H', '10:59', '11:03', 200.0, 1],
       ['11H-12H', '11:05', '11:09', 200.0, 1],
       ['11H-12H', '11:11', '11:15', 200.0, 1],
       ['11H-12H', '11:17', '11:21', 200.0, 1],
       ['11H-12H', '11:23', '11:27', 200.0, 1],
       ['11H-12H', '11:29', '11:33', 200.0, 1],
       ['11H-12H', '11:35', '11:39', 200.0, 1],
       ['11H-12H', '11:41', '11:46', 200.0, 1],
       ['11H-12H', '11:47', '11:51', 200.0, 1],
       ['11H-12H', '11:53', '11:57', 200.0, 1],
       ['11H-12H', '11:59', '12:03', 200.0, 1],
       ['12H-13H', '12:05', '12:09', 200.0, 1],
       ['12H-13H', '12:11', '12:15', 200.0, 1],
       ['12H-13H', '12:17', '12:21', 200.0, 1],
       ['12H-13H', '12:22', '12:26', 200.0, 1],
       ['12H-13H', '12:28', '12:33', 200.0, 1],
       ['12H-13H', '12:33', '12:37', 200.0, 1],
       ['12H-13H', '12:38', '12:43', 200.0, 1],
       ['12H-13H', '12:43', '12:47', 200.0, 1],
       ['12H-13H', '12:49', '12:53', 200.0, 1],
       ['12H-13H', '12:55', '12:59', 200.0, 1],
       ['13H-14H', '13:01', '13:05', 200.0, 1],
       ['13H-14H', '13:07', '13:12', 200.0, 1],
       ['13H-14H', '13:13', '13:17', 200.0, 1],
       ['13H-14H', '13:19', '13:23', 200.0, 1],
       ['13H-14H', '13:25', '13:29', 200.0, 1],
       ['13H-14H', '13:31', '13:35', 200.0, 1],
       ['13H-14H', '13:37', '13:41', 200.0, 1],
       ['13H-14H', '13:43', '13:47', 200.0, 1],
       ['13H-14H', '13:49', '13:53', 200.0, 1],
       ['13H-14H', '13:55', '13:59', 200.0, 1],
       ['14H-15H', '14:01', '14:06', 200.0, 1],
       ['14H-15H', '14:07', '14:11', 200.0, 1],
       ['14H-15H', '14:13', '14:17', 200.0, 1],
       ['14H-15H', '14:19', '14:23', 200.0, 1],
       ['14H-15H', '14:25', '14:29', 200.0, 1],
       ['14H-15H', '14:31', '14:35', 200.0, 1],
       ['14H-15H', '14:37', '14:41', 200.0, 1],
       ['14H-15H', '14:42', '14:46', 200.0, 1],
       ['14H-15H', '14:48', '14:52', 200.0, 1],
       ['14H-15H', '14:54', '14:58', 200.0, 1],
       ['14H-15H', '14:59', '15:03', 200.0, 1],
       ['15H-16H', '15:04', '15:08', 200.0, 1],
       ['15H-16H', '15:09', '15:13', 200.0, 1],
       ['15H-16H', '15:15', '15:19', 200.0, 1],
       ['15H-16H', '15:21', '15:25', 200.0, 1],
       ['15H-16H', '15:27', '15:31', 200.0, 1],
       ['15H-16H', '15:33', '15:37', 200.0, 1],
       ['15H-16H', '15:39', '15:43', 200.0, 1],
       ['15H-16H', '15:45', '15:49', 200.0, 1],
       ['15H-16H', '15:51', '15:55', 200.0, 1],
       ['15H-16H', '15:57', '16:01', 200.0, 1],
       ['16H-17H', '16:03', '16:07', 200.0, 1],
       ['16H-17H', '16:09', '16:13', 200.0, 1],
       ['16H-17H', '16:15', '16:19', 200.0, 1],
       ['16H-17H', '16:21', '16:27', 200.0, 1],
       ['16H-17H', '16:27', '16:31', 200.0, 1],
       ['16H-17H', '16:33', '16:37', 200.0, 1],
       ['16H-17H', '16:39', '16:43', 200.0, 1],
       ['16H-17H', '16:45', '16:49', 200.0, 1],
       ['16H-17H', '16:51', '16:55', 200.0, 1],
       ['16H-17H', '16:57', '17:01', 200.0, 1],
       ['17H-18H', '17:04', '17:08', 200.0, 1],
       ['17H-18H', '17:10', '17:14', 200.0, 1],
       ['17H-18H', '17:16', '17:20', 200.0, 1],
       ['17H-18H', '17:22', '17:26', 200.0, 1],
       ['17H-18H', '17:28', '17:32', 200.0, 1],
       ['17H-18H', '17:34', '17:38', 200.0, 1],
       ['17H-18H', '17:40', '17:44', 200.0, 1],
       ['17H-18H', '17:46', '17:50', 200.0, 1],
       ['17H-18H', '17:51', '17:55', 200.0, 1],
       ['17H-18H', '17:57', '18:01', 200.0, 1],
       ['18H-19H', '18:03', '18:07', 200.0, 1],
       ['18H-19H', '18:09', '18:13', 200.0, 1],
       ['18H-19H', '18:15', '18:19', 200.0, 1],
       ['18H-19H', '18:21', '18:25', 200.0, 1],
       ['18H-19H', '18:27', '18:31', 200.0, 1],
       ['18H-19H', '18:33', '18:37', 200.0, 1],
       ['18H-19H', '18:39', '18:43', 200.0, 1],
       ['18H-19H', '18:45', '18:49', 200.0, 1],
       ['18H-19H', '18:51', '18:55', 200.0, 1],
       ['18H-19H', '18:57', '19:01', 200.0, 1],
       ['19H-20H', '19:04', '19:08', 200.0, 1],
       ['19H-20H', '19:11', '19:15', 200.0, 1],
       ['19H-20H', '19:18', '19:22', 200.0, 1],
       ['19H-20H', '19:25', '19:29', 200.0, 1],
       ['19H-20H', '19:32', '19:36', 200.0, 1],
       ['19H-20H', '19:39', '19:43', 200.0, 1],
       ['19H-20H', '19:46', '19:50', 200.0, 1],
       ['19H-20H', '19:52', '19:56', 200.0, 1],
       ['20H-21H', '20:07', '20:11', 200.0, 1],
       ['20H-21H', '20:13', '20:17', 200.0, 1],
       ['20H-21H', '20:20', '20:24', 200.0, 1],
       ['20H-21H', '20:28', '20:32', 200.0, 1],
       ['20H-21H', '20:35', '20:39', 200.0, 1],
       ['20H-21H', '20:42', '20:46', 200.0, 1],
       ['20H-21H', '20:49', '20:53', 200.0, 1],
       ['20H-21H', '20:55', '20:59', 200.0, 1],
       ['21H-22H', '21:10', '21:14', 200.0, 1],
       ['21H-22H', '21:23', '21:24', 200.0, 1],
       ['21H-22H', '21:39', '21:43', 200.0, 1],
       ['22H-23H', '22:08', '22:12', 200.0, 1],
       ['22H-23H', '22:38', '22:42', 200.0, 1],
       ['23H-00H', '23:08', '23:12', 200.0, 1],
       ['23H-00H', '23:36', '23:40', 200.0, 1]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=mycolumns)
```

Comment: Do you mind to add the expected output? In other words you can produce a [mcve].

Comment: I just did it,thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Are you looking for something different than a groupby sum isn't it?

Comment: I tried with groupby and sum but I didn't get the desired output. It doesn't matter to me the way it's done, I just want it done **correctly**, possibly in a fast way. :)

Comment: I see. Anyway the kW between 19-20 should be 600 instead of 700. Do you mind to check?

Comment: no, it should be 700 because it counts also the vehicle charging in the 18-19h timeslot and it counts 2 vehicles charging at 19:54

Comment: I arranged a bit your code.

Comment: My prelim calculation for `20H-21H  is  3400 that is (index 0 to index 28)`, could you explain how 3100 is calculated?

Comment: @ferdy, the 3 vehicles at index `[0]` and `[4`] finish either at `20:19` or at `20:27`, so three of the already counted vehicles from index `[6]` and on can be charged at the same stations as these 3 that will finish at `20:19` or at `20:27` - that's why it's 3100kW - I hope I explained

Comment: Got it. Now for `21H-22H` I got this 4700 yours 4600. Mine `21H-22H             4700  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]` What could be the reason for the discrepancy?

Comment: @ferdy  for `21H-22H` some indexes have two vehicles charging at the exact time so we count them twice. We don't count indexes `[0]` and `[4]` because they finish before 21:00, neither do we count index `[50]` because it starts after 22:00. We also don't count indexes `[1,2,3,26,47,48]` because by the time they finish we can charge other indexes from `21H-22H` in those 6 stations. I hope I explained. :)

Comment: If `[47]` and `[48]` are excluded in `21H-22H` why `[46]` is not excluded?

Comment: It would be easier to solve if you provide timestamps instead of times (because of transitions to the next day).

Answer (score 3):

There are two main steps to this solution. First, you need to create a new column that you can group over. Simply using `start_timeslot` won't work as rows in earlier timeslots that have not stopped charging can still affect later `start_timeslot` groups.

New groups can be created using the `start` and `end` values together with [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html). Note that extra care must be taken when the end value is in a new day.

```
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])
df.loc[df['start'] > df['end'], 'end'] = df['end'] + pd.DateOffset(1)

df['hours'] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.date_range(row['start'].floor('H'), row['end'].floor('H'), freq='H').hour, axis=1)
```

Intermediate result:

```
   start_timeslot               start                 end  power_kW  vehicle_count                                        hours
0         18H-19H 2021-11-18 18:00:00 2021-11-18 20:00:00       100              1      Int64Index([18, 19, 20], dtype='int64')
1         19H-20H 2021-11-18 19:00:00 2021-11-18 21:00:00       100              1      Int64Index([19, 20, 21], dtype='int64')
2         19H-20H 2021-11-18 19:00:00 2021-11-18 21:00:00       100              1      Int64Index([19, 20, 21], dtype='int64')
3         19H-20H 2021-11-18 19:00:00 2021-11-18 21:00:00       100              1      Int64Index([19, 20, 21], dtype='int64')
4         19H-20H 2021-11-18 19:00:00 2021-11-18 20:00:00       100              2          Int64Index([19, 20], dtype='int64')
5         19H-20H 2021-11-18 19:00:00 2021-11-18 22:00:00       100              1  Int64Index([19, 20, 21, 22], dtype='int64')
```

Now, we can [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the new column and then group by it.

The second step is to compute the maximum required power for a group. We can simply take the start and end times and sort them. We consider the start time as positive (we add the required power) and end times as negative (subtract the power). Next, we sort by time and then use [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) on the series to get the cumulative sum and then take the maximum value of this. This will be the maximum required power for a group.

Code:

```
def func(df):
    df['power'] = df['power_kW'] * df['vehicle_count']
    pos = df.set_index('start')['power']
    neg = df.set_index('end')['power'] * -1
    df_merge = pd.concat([pos, neg]).reset_index()
    maximum = df_merge.sort_values(['index', 'power'], ascending=[True, False])['power'].cumsum().max()
    return maximum

res = df.explode('hours').groupby('hours').apply(func)
```

Note that if there is a car that *stops* charging at e.g. 10:35 and another one that *starts* at 10:35, this will be considered an overlap with the above code. If these should not overlap then change the sorting to use `ascending=[True, True]`.

Result:

```
hours
0      600
18     100
19     700
20    3100
21    4700
22    4600
23    1800
dtype: int64
```

The `start_timeslot` column is gone so some final postprocessing to obtain the expected result is required:

```
res = res.to_frame('needed_power_kW').reset_index().rename(columns={'hours': 'start_timeslot'})
res['end_hour'] = (pd.to_datetime(res['start_timeslot'], unit='h') + pd.DateOffset(hours=1)).dt.hour
res['start_timeslot'] = res['start_timeslot'].astype(str).str.zfill(2) + 'H-' + res['end_hour'].astype(str).str.zfill(2) + 'H'
res = res.drop('end_hour', axis=1)
```

Final result:

```
  start_timeslot  needed_power_kW
0        00H-01H              600
1        18H-19H              100
2        19H-20H              700
3        20H-21H             3100
4        21H-22H             4600
5        22H-23H             4600
6        23H-00H             1800
```

Using the additional data:

```
  start_timeslot  needed_power_kW
0        00H-01H            200.0
1        01H-02H            200.0
2        05H-06H            200.0
3        06H-07H            200.0
4        07H-08H            200.0
5        08H-09H            400.0
6        09H-10H            400.0
7        10H-11H            400.0
8        11H-12H            200.0
9        12H-13H            400.0
10       13H-14H            200.0
11       14H-15H            200.0
12       15H-16H            200.0
13       16H-17H            400.0
14       17H-18H            200.0
15       18H-19H            200.0
16       19H-20H            200.0
17       20H-21H            200.0
18       21H-22H            200.0
19       22H-23H            200.0
20       23H-00H            200.0
```

Note: by changing the sorting as described above, the `needed_power_kW` for both `12H-13H` and `16H-17H` will be 200.

Comment: Thank you for this solution, I understand the reasoning of your code. It works for this sample data, but when I run the code on the real data, situations where in one hour I have one vehicle charging for example from 6:13-6:36 and another one from 6:45-6:55 are counted as double needed power instead of just 1*power. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @ctrl_z: I see. I think that the expected output from your example should be a bit different as well then? For example line 48 starts at 21:58 and line 35 stops at 21:56, so the '21H-22H' should be less than 4600. Can you confirm if this is correct?

Comment: no, because if the time overlaps we have to count double (even taking into account some vehicles that let's say started charging at 20:16 and finished at 21:47) so they have to be counted all according to the HH:MM timing in which they start and finish, not only the timeslot

Comment: @ctrl_z: I added an adjusted method where the minute information is kept. You can see if it works correctly on the complete data (I tested a case such as you mentioned and it looks to work fine).

Comment: @ctrl_z: Note that the result with minute gives 4700 for 21H-22H, I think it's due to the case where one car stops at 21:33 and another one starts at the same time.

Comment: I added the real data example, because with the proposed solution I still get the wrong numbers :/

Comment: @ctrl_z: Could you add the expected output as well? I will try to take a look at it tomorrow (Hong Kong time).

Comment: @ctrl_z: I added result on the real data example (2 versions depending on the wanted behaviour with end/start at the same time).

Answer (score 2):

I would propose this approach.
First, change all the times to minutes per day. (If you have a larger dataset over days, you could adapt the code below using `datetime` objects with the appropriate resolution, e.g. seconds.) That is done using the following function

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def toMinutes(timeString):
    t = [int(i) for i in timeString.split(':')]
    t = 60 * t[0] + t[1]
    return(t)
```

Next, I would iterate through your dataset noting the times where there were increases and decreases in usage along with the amount of power. You don't explicitly mention tracking the number of vehicles in your question but I am going to track that as well as power since they are pretty much the same from a counting point of view.

```
def add_row(timeString, power, nVehicle, arrive = True):
    t = toMinutes(timeString)
    delta = power * nVehicle
    if arrive:
        return([t / 60, delta, nVehicle])
    else:
        return([t  / 60, -delta, - nVehicle])
```

Running through your `dataframe` we can create a list of times where vehicles arrived or left and monitor the resulting change in power consumption. So each entry in your `dataframe` results in two entries in the list below, one when the vehicle arrives and one when it leaves.
You stated in your question that a vehicle arriving at 20:50 and another leaving at 20:50 had to count as two vehicles at 20:50, so do all the arrivals first and then all the departures. That way when you sort below, it will count the arrivals before the departures.

```
x = [[0, 0, 0],] # initialize list (mostly for plotting, you can skip this if not plotting)

x += [add_row(t, P, n) \
     for t, P, n in zip(df['start'], df['power_kW'], df['vehicle_count'])]
     
x += [add_row(t, P, n, arrive = False) \
      for t, P, n in zip(df['end'], df['power_kW'], df['vehicle_count'])]
```

Now sort `x` by the time column so we have an ordered time series of discrete events that we care about. The power consumption and number of vehicles is just the sum of past events in our dataset.

```
x = np.array(sorted(x))
t = x[:,0]
P = np.cumsum(x[:,1])
N = np.cumsum(x[:,2])
```

I like plotting things so here is a script to make sure the code is doing what we want so far.

```
def plot_events(t, P, n):
    Nevent = len(P)
    to = []
    Po = []
    No = []
    for i in range(1, Nevent):
        to.append(t[i])
        to.append(t[i])
        Po.append(P[i-1])
        Po.append(P[i])
        No.append(N[i-1])
        No.append(N[i])

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (6,8), nrows=2)
    ax[0].plot(to, Po)
    ax[0].set_xlabel('Time in Hours')
    ax[0].set_ylabel('Power in kW')

    ax[1].plot(to, No)
    ax[1].set_xlabel('Time in Hours')
    ax[1].set_ylabel('Number of vehicles charging')
    return(fig, ax)

fig, ax = plot_events(t, P, N)
```

[image: events]

Now to bin the events in time, we just look at the maximum demand in each time window of interest.

```
def bin_events(t, y, dt = 1, mint = 0, maxt = 24):
    # find max value of y in t bins of size dt
    x = np.arange(mint, maxt, dt)
    z = np.zeros(x.shape)
    for i in range(len(x)):
        try:
            z[i] = np.max(y[(t >= x[i]) & (t < x[i] + dt)])
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return(z)

maxP = bin_events(t, P)
maxN = bin_events(t, N)
```

And again, plot to make sure we're doing what we want:

```
ax[0].bar(np.arange(0,24) + 0.5, maxP, color = 'k', alpha = 0.3, width = 1)
ax[1].bar(np.arange(0,24) + 0.5, maxN, color = 'k', alpha = 0.3, width = 1)
```

[image: events with max values]

Finally, put the new info to a `dataframe` or add it to your existing one:

```
col = 'start_timeslot'
choices = [f"{i:02}H-{(i+1)%24:02}H" for i in range(24)]
conditions = [eval(f"df[col] == '{c}'") for c in choices]
summary_data_df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([choices, maxP, maxN]).transpose(),
                               columns=['start_timeslot', 'max_power_kW', 'max_vehicles'])    

df["max_power_kW"] = np.select(conditions, maxP, default=0)
df["max_vehicles"] = np.select(conditions, maxN, default=0)
```

```
   start_timeslot max_power_kW max_vehicles
0         00H-01H        200.0          1.0
1         01H-02H        200.0          1.0
2         02H-03H          0.0          0.0
3         03H-04H          0.0          0.0
4         04H-05H          0.0          0.0
5         05H-06H        200.0          1.0
6         06H-07H        200.0          1.0
7         07H-08H        200.0          1.0
8         08H-09H        400.0          2.0
9         09H-10H        400.0          2.0
10        10H-11H        400.0          2.0
11        11H-12H        200.0          1.0
12        12H-13H        200.0          1.0
13        13H-14H        200.0          1.0
14        14H-15H        200.0          1.0
15        15H-16H        200.0          1.0
16        16H-17H        200.0          1.0
17        17H-18H        200.0          1.0
18        18H-19H        200.0          1.0
19        19H-20H        200.0          1.0
20        20H-21H        200.0          1.0
21        21H-22H        200.0          1.0
22        22H-23H        200.0          1.0
23        23H-00H        200.0          1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer to your question. Code is below:

```
    import pandas as pd
mycolumns = ['start_timeslot', 'start', 'end', 'power_kW', 'vehicle_count']                 #Column header
data = [['18H-19H', '18:26', '20:27', 100, 1], ['19H-20H', '19:06', '21:16', 100, 1],       #Data
        ['19H-20H', '19:19', '21:16', 100, 1], ['19H-20H', '19:36', '21:33', 100, 1], 
        ['19H-20H', '19:54', '20:19', 100, 2], ['19H-20H', '19:55', '22:01', 100, 1],
        ['20H-21H', '20:04', '22:06', 100, 1], ['20H-21H', '20:11', '22:04', 100, 2], 
        ['20H-21H', '20:15', '22:04', 100, 1], ['20H-21H', '20:16', '22:04', 100, 1], 
        ['20H-21H', '20:17', '22:08', 100, 1], ['20H-21H', '20:19', '22:09', 100, 1],
        ['20H-21H', '20:20', '22:01', 100, 2], ['20H-21H', '20:22', '22:35', 100, 1], 
        ['20H-21H', '20:28', '22:34', 100, 2], ['20H-21H', '20:29', '22:22', 100, 1], 
        ['20H-21H', '20:30', '22:14', 100, 1], ['20H-21H', '20:31', '22:10', 100, 1],
        ['20H-21H', '20:37', '22:31', 100, 1], ['20H-21H', '20:41', '22:29', 100, 2], 
        ['20H-21H', '20:43', '22:34', 100, 1], ['20H-21H', '20:46', '22:39', 100, 1], 
        ['20H-21H', '20:47', '22:35', 100, 1], ['20H-21H', '20:52', '22:34', 100, 1],
        ['20H-21H', '20:52', '23:09', 100, 1], ['20H-21H', '20:53', '21:59', 100, 1], 
        ['20H-21H', '20:54', '21:49', 100, 1], ['20H-21H', '20:56', '22:10', 100, 1], 
        ['20H-21H', '20:56', '22:55', 100, 1], ['21H-22H', '21:03', '22:51', 100, 1],
        ['21H-22H', '21:05', '23:12', 100, 1], ['21H-22H', '21:08', '22:59', 100, 1], 
        ['21H-22H', '21:10', '23:27', 100, 1], ['21H-22H', '21:10', '23:30', 100, 1], 
        ['21H-22H', '21:15', '23:23', 100, 1], ['21H-22H', '21:19', '21:56', 100, 1],
        ['21H-22H', '21:21', '22:48', 100, 1], ['21H-22H', '21:25', '23:26', 100, 1], 
        ['21H-22H', '21:25', '23:32', 100, 1], ['21H-22H', '21:27', '22:55', 100, 1], 
        ['21H-22H', '21:27', '23:32', 100, 1], ['21H-22H', '21:33', '23:11', 100, 1],
        ['21H-22H', '21:37', '23:04', 100, 1], ['21H-22H', '21:39', '00:05', 100, 1], 
        ['21H-22H', '21:40', '23:08', 100, 1], ['21H-22H', '21:45', '23:04', 100, 1], 
        ['21H-22H', '21:49', '00:06', 100, 1], ['21H-22H', '21:54', '00:07', 100, 1],
        ['21H-22H', '21:58', '00:02', 100, 1], ['21H-22H', '21:58', '00:24', 100, 1], 
        ['22H-23H', '22:10', '00:19', 100, 1]]
        

per_hour_columns = ['hour', 'power_kW']         #Header for individual vehicles
per_hour = []       #Empty data

x = 0
while(x < len(data)):       #Loop through all data
    y = int(data[x][1].split(':')[0])
    while(y != int(data[x][2].split(':')[0])+1):      #Loop though all hours the vehicle stayed
        if(y >= 24):
            y = 0
        i = 0
        while(i < data[x][4]):          #Loop through number of vehicles
            per_hour.append([str(y), data[x][3]])       #Append vehicle to array
            i+=1
        y+=1
    x+=1

per_hour_df = pd.DataFrame(per_hour, columns=per_hour_columns)      #Turn to dataframe


total_hours_header = ['time_slot', 'total_power_kW']        #header for total power per time slot
total_hours = []

i = 0
while(i < 24):      #Loop through all hours
    total = int(per_hour_df[per_hour_df['hour'] == str(i)].sum()[1])        #Get total for timeslot
    total_hours.append([str(i) + "H-" + str(i+1) + "H", total])             #Append time slot to array
    i+=1

total_hours_df = pd.DataFrame(total_hours, columns=total_hours_header)      #Turn to dataframe

print(total_hours_df)       #Print
```

I hope this works for you.

Output:

```
          time_slot  total_power_kW
0      0H-1H             600
1      1H-2H               0
2      2H-3H               0
3      3H-4H               0
4      4H-5H               0
5      5H-6H               0
6      6H-7H               0
7      7H-8H               0
8      8H-9H               0
9     9H-10H               0
10   10H-11H               0
11   11H-12H               0
12   12H-13H               0
13   13H-14H               0
14   14H-15H               0
15   15H-16H               0
16   16H-17H               0
17   17H-18H               0
18   18H-19H             100
19   19H-20H             700
20   20H-21H            3400
21   21H-22H            5200
22   22H-23H            4700
23   23H-24H            1800
```

To explain:
I first create a new array which has one slot per vehicle (instead of having a vehicle count greater than 1). I also duplicate each vehicle for every hour is stayed.
Next I looped through all hours (0-24) and appended the sum of all the elements with the current hour I am trying to find to a new array.
This gives you an array which contains all 24 time slots with their corresponding power usage.

EDIT:
I have changed the code slightly so that it records times that pass from hour 23 to 00